# Python: Indices of identical tuple elements are also identical?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tuples

just starting out so I apologize if this is a stupid question. Python 2.7 if it's important. I'm writing a program that evaluates a polynomial whose coefficients are represented by the elements of a tuple at some x whose power is the index of the coefficient. It runs fine when all the coefficients are different, the issue I'm having is when any of the coefficients are the same. Code is below -

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
"""polynomial coefficients represented by elements of tuple.
    each coefficient evaluated at x ** index of coefficient"""
    poly_sum = 0.0
    for coefficient in poly:
        val = coefficient * (x ** poly.index(coefficient))
        poly_sum += val
    return poly_sum

poly = (1, 2, 3)
x = 5

print evaluate_poly(poly, x)

##for coefficient in poly:
    ##print poly.index(coefficient)
```

Which returns 86 as you would expect.

The commented out print statement will return the indices of each element in poly. When they're all different (1, 2, 3) it returns what you would expect (0, 1, 2) but if any of the elements are the same (1, 1, 2) their indices will also be the same (0, 0, 1), so I'm really only able to evaluate polynomials where all the coefficients are different. What am I doing wrong here? I figure it has something to do with -

```
poly.index(coefficient)
```

but I can't figure out why exactly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate), index will get the index of the *first* occurrence so for repeated elements it will obviously fail, in your code `poly.index(1)` using `(1, 1, 2)` is going to return `0` each time:

Uusing enumerate will give you each actual index of every element and also more efficiently:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """polynomial coefficients represented by elements of tuple.
    each coefficient evaluated at x ** index of coefficient"""
    poly_sum = 0.0
    # ind is each index, coefficient  is each element
    for ind, coefficient in enumerate(poly):
        # no need for val just += coefficient * (x ** ind)
        poly_sum += coefficient * (x ** ind)
    return poly_sum
```

If you `print(list(enumerate(poly)))` you will see each element and it's index in the list:

```
[(0, 1), (1, 1), (2, 3)]
```

So `ind` each time in the loop refers to the index of each `coefficient`   in your poly list.

You can also just return  a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) expression using [sum](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum):

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):
    """polynomial coefficients represented by elements of tuple.
    each coefficient evaluated at x ** index of coefficient"""
    return sum((coefficient * (x ** ind)  for ind, coefficient in enumerate(poly)),0.0)
```

using `0.0` as the *start* value will mean a float is returned as opposed to an int. You could also cast `float(sum...` but i think it is simpler just to pass the start value as a float.

Comment: Much appreciated. How does Python differentiate between 'ind' and 'coefficient' in the 'for' statement?

Comment: @Brendan, you are unpacking the tuples in the loop, the first element in each tuple is the ind/index the second if the element from the list, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Tuples#Packing_and_Unpacking

Answer (score 0):

try this one here:

```
def evaluate_poly(poly, x):

    '''
    polynomial coefficients represented by elements of tuple.
    each coefficient evaluated at x ** index of coefficient
    '''

    poly_sum = 0.0

    for ind, coefficient in enumerate(poly):
        print ind
        val = coefficient * (x ** ind)
        poly_sum += val
    return poly_sum

poly = (1, 2, 3)

x = 5

print evaluate_poly(poly, x)
```

it works with `poly = (1, 1, 3)` too!